# Missing YAML syntax dumped using python

Tags: python, yaml

I'm reading a such yaml file in python:

```
- test:
    name: test1
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2
```

First I parse the file, then I apply some changes to it, and finally I dump it into multiple files.

```
def read_test():
     with open('file.yaml', "r") as stream:
        test = yaml.load(stream)



def write_test(config):
     with open('test.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(config, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

This is the output I get:

```
test:
  name: test1
  param:
    p1: localhost:3000
    p2: ../test/run.sh
```

But I expect this:

```
- test:
    name: test1
    param:
      p1: localhost:3000
      p2: ../test/run.sh
```

#### UPDATE

This is how I apply changes:

```
def split_test():
  try:
    tests = read_test()
    for config in tests:          
      write_test(config)
  except yaml.YAMLError as out:
    print(out)
```

This function changes the final output's syntax. Any help?

Comment: Your code has errors. I guess `file.yaml` and `test.yaml` should be strings. furthermore, you have a `return` statement inside the first `with` which renders the following code as unreachable. Please fix the code so that we can see where the `test` variable's value comes from.

Comment: The code you have given yields the correct output for me (it needs an additional `import yaml` to actually work).

Comment: @flyx With the current output without "-" I'm not able to read the yaml file properly. I need the file with the mentioned syntax.

Comment: Your code gives me the output with the `-`. What version of Python and PyYaml are you using?

Comment: @flyx python --version
Python 2.7.6

Comment: Well I am at `Python 2.7.12`. Did you try to run the exact code as shown here?

Comment: @flyx I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error here, your code is behaving exactly how you tell it to.

```
tests = read_test()
```

Okay, you read the original file and store the result in `tests`.

```
for config in tests:
```

Now you iterate over the content of the original file. Which is a YAML sequence, so it is fine to iterate over it.

```
  write_test(config)
```

Some remarks here:

- This will be executed *for each config item* of the input YAML.
- As `write_test` always writes the same file, this will overwrite `test.yaml` again and again for  each config item.
- Since `config` contains only the value of a list item, *of course* the list itself is not part of the YAML that is written.

To get the output you want, simply replace these two lines:

```
for config in tests:          
  write_test(config)
```

with:

```
write_test(tests)
```

*Note:* Based on the naming of your functions, you *want* to split the file into multiple files. However, in the question's description, you describe that you only want to load it, modify it and then dump it again. You should probably be more clear in describing what you want to do.